# How to set the height for a specific row in a "longtable"?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have a "longtable" and I need a couple of rows to be "taller" than the others. Is it possible to specify a fixed height for a specific row?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\rule{0pt}{whatever_you_want}
```

is the better choice and if you need a depth:

```
\rule[shift]{0pt}{whatever_you_want}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, I've created an empty box within the cell, like this:

```
\vbox to 1cm {\vfil
\hbox to 3cm{}%
\vfil
}
```

Probably not the best method to do this, but it works.